# How do I specify a default value in vaadin-combo-box?

Tags: typescript, vaadin, lit

I have created a combo box component using lit and vaadin-combo-box.
I was able to create the combo box without any problems, but I don't know how to set the default value.
How can I set the default value to "Label 1" before selecting it?

```
import {customElement} from 'lit/decorators.js';
import {html, LitElement} from 'lit';

const items = [
  {'label': 'Label 1', 'value': 'label1'},
  {'label': 'Label 2', 'value': 'label2'},
];

@customElement('my-element')
export class MyElement extends LitElement {
  render() {
    return html`
      <vaadin-combo-box
          label="combo box"
          .items="${items}"
          required
      >
      </vaadin-combo-box>
    `;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For setting the default element, you can set the `selectedItem` property of the object.

```js
const el = this.shadowRoot.getElementById('my-box');
el.selectedItem = items[0].label;
```

See [this](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-combo-box/html-api/elements/Vaadin.ComboBoxElement) for more reference.

In addition, you can also set the value in the HTML element directly:

```html
<vaadin-combo-box value="${items[0].label}"></vaadin-combo-box>
```